# difference between if continue vs while in leetcode#917

Tags: javascript

problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-only-letters/description/

Can someone explain why reverseOnlyLettersNestedLoop doesn't work?

```
//this doesn't work
var reverseOnlyLettersNestedLoop = function(s) {
    let initArr = s.split('')
    let left = 0
    let right = initArr.length - 1
    function isLetter(char) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char);
    }
   
    while (left < right) {
         
        while(isLetter(initArr[left]) === false) {
            left ++
        }
        while(isLetter(initArr[right]) === false) {
            right--
        }
        let temp = initArr[left]
        initArr[left] = initArr[right]
        initArr[right] = temp
        left++
        right--
    }    
    return initArr.join('')
};
```

```
//this works
var reverseOnlyLetters = function(s) {
    let initArr = s.split('')
    let left = 0
    let right = initArr.length - 1
    function isLetter(char) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char);
    }
   
    while (left < right) {
         
        if (isLetter(initArr[left]) === false) {
            left ++
            continue;
        }
        if (isLetter(initArr[right]) === false) {
            right--
            continue;
        }
        let temp = initArr[left]
        initArr[left] = initArr[right]
        initArr[right] = temp
        left++
        right--
    }    
    return initArr.join('')

};
```

I expect the nested while loops to only in/de-crement left/right if encounters a non-letter.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that works you check that left < right on each increment/decrement of left and right. In the nested code left may be >= right because there is no check.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work

- Check if `left < right` in your while loop that checks `isLetter`
- In case `left >= right`, break out of the loop

**Code**

```js
var reverseOnlyLetters = function(s) {
    
    let initArr = s.split('')
    let left = 0
    let right = initArr.length - 1
    
    function isLetter(char) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char);
    }
   
    while (left < right) {

        while(left < right && isLetter(initArr[left]) === false) { left ++ }
        while(left < right && isLetter(initArr[right]) === false) { right-- }
        if (left >= right) break;
        
        let temp = initArr[left]
        initArr[left] = initArr[right]
        initArr[right] = temp
        left++
        right--
    }
    
    return initArr.join('')
};
```